# renderDataTable or Table in Shiny on actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm working on a Shiny app that plots a histogram of my daily steps in Fitbit among other things. It's basically a work in progress to build a complete dashboard of fitness metrics. Right now I'm just working with the daily steps to get a handle on it while I figure out the API scrape via OAuth2.0.

Anywho, everything I have is working so far with the histogram, plotting, scaling, and such. What I am missing and cannot seem to figure out even with numerous reads through the Shiny literature and Stack for examples but seem to be missing the mark somewhere. I've tried reactives, eventReactive, eventObserve, isolate, observe, etc.

So, with that in mind, could someone help me figure out how to render a print out of the dplyr summarise table that I have created in this code?

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Data Products - Final Project"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Select some of the features of the histogram."),

      sliderInput("bins", label = h4("Number of bins: ")
                  , min = 5
                  , max = 50
                  , value = 10),
      radioButtons("radio-color", helpText(h5("Select a color for density plot.")),
                   choices = list("Salmon" = "salmon", "Black" = "black"
                                  ,"Red" = "red", "Dark Blue" = "darkblue"
                                  , "Dark Grey" = "darkgrey")
                   ,selected = "salmon"),
      helpText(h5("Select some plot overlays")),
      checkboxInput("checkCurve", label = "Curve", value = FALSE), 
      checkboxInput("checkMean", label = "Mean", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkMed", label = "Median", value = FALSE),
      helpText(h5("Generate daily summary statistics?")),
      actionButton("tableButton", label = "Generate")
    ),#end sideBarPanel

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(p(icon("line-chart"), "Visualize Data"),
             plotOutput("histPlot", height = "400px")
    ), #end viz tab
    tabPanel(p(icon("about"), "About")) #end dataset tab

  ), #end tabsetPanel
  tableOutput("table")
   )#End mainPanel
  )#End sidebarLayout
 )#End fluidPage
)#End ShinyUI
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

dat <- fread("data/fitbit_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "0")
dat$Day <- weekdays(x = as.Date(dat$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"
                                ,label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE))
dat$Steps <- as.numeric(sub(",","",dat$Steps))
dat$`Calories Burned` <- as.numeric(sub(",","",dat$`Calories Burned`))
dat$`Minutes Sedentary` <- as.numeric(sub(",","",dat$`Minutes Sedentary`))
dat$`Activity Calories` <- as.numeric(sub(",","",dat$`Activity Calories`))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$histPlot <- renderPlot({
    steps <- dat$Steps
    bins <- seq(min(steps, na.rm = TRUE), max(steps, na.rm = TRUE)
                , length.out = input$bins + 1)

    h <- hist(dat$Steps, breaks = bins, density = 45, col = input$`radio-color`
         , xlim = c(500, 25000)
         , ylim = c(0, 25)
         , xlab = "# of Steps"
         , ylab = "Frequency"
         , main = "Histogram of Steps")

    m <- mean(dat$Steps, na.rm = TRUE)
    s <- sqrt(var(dat$Steps, na.rm = TRUE))
    md <- median(dat$Steps, na.rm = TRUE)
    xfit <- seq(min(dat$Steps, na.rm = TRUE)
                , max(dat$Steps, na.rm = TRUE), length = 40)
    yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = m, sd = s)
    yfit2 <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(dat$Steps)

   if(input$checkCurve == TRUE) {
          lines(xfit, yfit2, col = "darkblue", lwd = 2)
     }#end plot-curve if 
    if(input$checkMean == TRUE) {
       abline(v = m, lwd = 2, col = "blue")    
     }#end plot-mean-if
    if(input$checkMed == TRUE) {
      abline(v = md, lwd = 2, col = "red") 
     }#end plot-median-if
    })#end renderPlot

output$table <- renderTable({
  if(input$tableButton == 0) {return()}
  else{
    dat %>%
      group_by(Day) %>%
      summarise(., total = sum(Steps, na.rm=TRUE)
                , avg = mean(Steps, na.rm=TRUE)
                , stdev = sd(Steps, na.rm = TRUE)
                , min = min(Steps, na.rm = TRUE)
                , max = max(Steps, na.rm = TRUE)
                , med = median(Steps, na.rm = TRUE))
  }
})


})#end shinyServer
```

**Update on solution**

The tableOutput("table") needed to be moved from inside tabSetPanel outside of it but inside of the mainPanel(). Now it plots wonderfully.

Comment: The results of `dplyr::summarise` is still a data.frame, so you can use anything you'd otherwise use to display one. `shiny::renderDataTable` and the `DT` package's more customizable version are nice, but just `renderTable` should do it.

Comment: I've tried the renderTable, renderDataTable and it doesn't seem to be dropping the information in my plot on actionButton click. It does nothing.

Comment: Is there data there?

Comment: Yep, there is data. My histogram plots and if I remove the renderTable pieces and just do a print then the dataframe will print to the console.

Comment: Oh, in `ui.R` it's in a `tabSetPanel`, but not a `tabPanel`. Move your parentheses and it'll probably show up.

Comment: <FACE PALM> <HEAD DESK>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tableOutput("table") needed to be moved from inside tabSetPanel outside of it but inside of the mainPanel(). Now it plots wonderfully.